# Always Open mp3 files with QuickTime

Tags: quicktime

Currently the default application for mp3 files on my Macbook Pro (10.6.8) is iTunes. I want to change it to QuickTime. So I right click on an mp3 file, select Other, check the Always open with box, scroll down to QuickTime select it, then click Open. The mp3 file plays with QuickTime. Bueno.

However, when I click another mp3 file, it plays with ITunes. I want all mp3 files to always play with QuickTime. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As detailed in [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42539/how-to-change-the-default-application-for-a-file-type-in-mac-os-x/), right-click on an MP3 file, click "Get Info" and open the "Open with" section. Choose QuickTime Player as the app OS X should use, and click "Change All...".
[image]